# How to set array value to a field in golang using reflect?

Tags: reflection, go

I have a Struct with following fields

```
type Config struct {
        Address[]string
        Name string
}
```

I am reading the values for this Config from a file in JSON format

```
{
   "Address": ["xx.xx.xx.xx","xx.xx.xx.xx"],
   "Name":"Name"
}
```

I have used Reflect to identify the type and set its value to Config.I am able to set the value of Name field using 
**func (v Value) SetString(x string)** which is an inbuilt method in reflect. Is there a way to set []string values directly to a field? Please help.

Comment: Why aren't you using the default json decoder from the standard library? It does everything for you already.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the json package for that (it uses reflect internally):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Config struct {
    Address []string
    Name    string
}

var someJson = []byte(`{
   "Address": ["xx.xx.xx.xx","xx.xx.xx.xx"],
   "Name":"Name"
}`)

func main() {
    var config Config
    err := json.Unmarshal(someJson, &config)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error: ", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", config)
}
```